# How to return a string for a double method in java

Tags: java

I'm new to java, I have to a write `withdraw` method that checks if there is enough in the account.
If the account balance is going below `0`, it just prints out a message saying `Insufficient funds`.

I've tried the following:

```
public double withdraw(double accountbalance) {
    if(accountbalance <= 0) {
        return "Insufficient funds";
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this method **subtract** something? Also, `print` != `return`.

Comment: Personally I would throw an Exception `InsufficientFundsException` **But** we really need to know what the logic of this method is supposed to do and **how** it is called

Comment: `going to go below zero` but zero is not below zero, you should use `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Not related to your specific question, but using `double` for currency is a terrible idea in general.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the method name `withdraw(...)`, I believe it is supposed to have subtraction here, there should be `accountbalance` and `withdrawAmount`, **Insufficient value** should be `accountbalance<withdrawAmount`

You need to modify return type from `double` to `String`

```
public String withdraw(double accountbalance)
 {
     if(accountbalance <=0){
         return "Insufficient funds";
     }
     return "Suffcient";
 }
```

Alternatively, I suggest returning `double`, if there's no sufficient value, just return 0. otherwise return the amount you requested

Comment: this gives me the following error: The return type is incompatible with Account.withdraw(double)

Comment: @Michael Your question doesn't compile itself either. Do you want to `return` a `String` or `return` a `double`?

Comment: @cricket_007 i need it to return a string

Comment: @Michael if you want to *return* String, you have to change the return type to String in the method signature

Answer (score 0):

Change your return type to String instead of Double

```
public String withDraw(double accountbalance) {
    if(accountbalance<=0) {
        return "Insfufficient funds";
    }
    return "Money is there";
}
```

Comment: Why -1 is given to the answer this is correct answer per question

Comment: i don't know whos downvoting these answers. they are all valid. i give them all a up vote

Comment: Those answers are correct if you take the question literally, but they do not solve the problem behind taking in account, that the user is new to Java and probably programming in general. The question behind is how to switch return types according to specific conditions. The string shall __only__ be returned, if there are not enough funds. Otherwise another return type is desired.

Answer (score 0):

you need return a String no double
and must be outside the if. for example:

```
public String withdraw(double accountbalance)
   String str="";

   if (accountbalance <= 0)
   {
     str="Insufficient funds"; 
   }
   return str;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would argue, that a negative account balance is an exception and should therefore be implemented as such.

```
public double withdraw(double amount) {
  if (accountBalance - amount < 0) {
    // throwing an exception ends the method
    // similar to a return statement
    throw new IllegalStateException("Insufficient funds");
  }
  // this is only executed,
  // if the above exception was not triggered
  this.accountBalance -= amount;
}
```

Now you can call this like this:

```
public String balance(double amount) {
  // to handle potentially failing scenarios use try-catch
  try {
    double newBalance = this.account.withDraw(amount)
    // return will only be executed,
    // if the above call does not yield an exception
    return String.format(
      "Successfully withdrawn %.2f, current balance %.2f", 
      amount,  
      newBalance
    );
  // to handle exceptions, you need to catch them
  // exceptions, you don't catch will be raised further up
  } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    return String.format(
      "Cannot withdraw %.2f: %s", 
      e.getMessage()
    );
  }
}
```

`String.format` is a handy utility for formating `Strings` without the clutter of concatenating them. It uses placeholders, which are replaced by the variables after the format `String` in there respective order.

`%s` represents a `String`.

`%f` is a placeholder, for floating point numbers. In the above case, I used `%.2f` which formats the floating point number to 2 digits after the decimal point.

More information about exception handling can be found in the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/) or in [one of the many tutorials](https://intellipaat.com/tutorial/java-tutorial/java-exception-handling/) about the topic.